# "File Was Not Uploaded"

Tags: products-management, image-upload

I am attempting to upload images to my products on a Magento site. It is a fresh install of Magento, running on a GoDaddy shared hosting server. It has been previously running on this server, set up by somebody else, so I know it to be possible with some tweaks. I do not know if the tweaks are needed to be made to the server, to Magento, or what. So here it is:

In Catalog > Manage Products > Product > Images - I have a flash interface for uploading images for the chosen product. I have the browse and upload buttons, and I elect my image and then press "Upload Files" button. I get a red box that states "File was not uploaded.". I have done hours of research into this issue and there seems to be no clear answer but I will lay out the solutions I have tried:

- Change browser, computer, clear local cache and cookies etc.
- Check permissions for /media/ folder (tried 777 and 755).
- Read and implemented changes to .htaccess for GoDaddy servers as explained by the .htaccess file in Magento root
- Disabled store view, flushed cache, logged out from Magento, deleted cache from /var/cache/ and then re-enabled store view, cleared cache again
- Uploaded and called an earlier version of Prototype.js
- Uploaded a local version of jQuery as I read that Prototype and jQuery can conflict and this was the suggested solution
- Checked that the GD extension is installed in my server's PHP build.

I must note that Magento is installed in a subdirectory on my server, however it has not moved from when I first installed it so I don't think there should be any issues with the pathing getting messed up.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: How do you mean "what is the error"? When I try to upload an image, I see the percentage bar go from 0% to 100% but then the red box reads "File was not uploaded". There is no error code reported.

Comment: Are you using git?

Comment: I'm not using git, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any way that I may be helped without the use of Git? I've been looking into Git but it seems very advanced for my knowledge. The install is presently on an empty database with no theme installed at all, as I want to remove all potential conflicting factors.

Comment: My suggestion is first enable error reporting. <br> Then you can get the exact error or issue with error code. This may help you to find the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can try these methods to get rid of the problem
1.) Rename your .htaccess file located inside the “media” directory to for example .htaccess_bak
2.) If the problem still exists, you can take a look into it "http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2011/09/upload-issue-for-magento-1600.html"